# Sqlite : format an integer

Tags: sqlite

Is it possible to format an integer column to have a comma as a thousandth digit separator in Sqlite? I would like the query result to be as follows.

```
Id  Name      Price
1   Product1  1,000
2   Product2  2,500
```

Comment: Sqlite doesn't know about formatting, unless you make it a character field.  The program you use to extract the data is responsible for formatting.

Comment: Ideally the environment you're calling SQLite from handles that.

Answer (score 2):

There is not an internal number formatting function built into SQLite, but you can create a [user-defined function](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html) to create one.

Here's a working example. Uses integers and will need adjustment for floats.

```
#import <sqlite3.h>
static char *sepnum(int num, char *buf, size_t buflen, char sepch)
{
    int len = 0, negative = 0;
    if (!buf || buflen == 0) return buf;
    if (num < 0)
    {
        negative = 1;
        num = abs(num);
    }
    for (int i=1;;i++)
    {
        if (buflen>len+1) buf[len++] = '0' + (num % 10);
        num /= 10;
        if (num==0) break;
        if ((i % 3) == 0 && buflen>len+1) buf[len++] = sepch;
    }
    if (negative && buflen>len+1) buf[len++] = '-';
    for (int i=0;i<len/2;i++)
    {
        buf[len] = buf[i];
        buf[i] = buf[len-i-1];
        buf[len-i-1] = buf[len];
    }
    if (buflen>len) buf[len] = '\0';
    else buf[0] = '\0';
    return buf;
}
static void nformat(sqlite3_context *context, int argc, sqlite3_value **argv)
{
   if (argc == 1) 
    {
        int num = sqlite3_value_int(argv[0]);
        char buf[500] = "";
        if (sepnum(num, buf, sizeof(buf), ','))
        {
            sqlite3_result_text(context, buf, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            return;
        }
   }
  sqlite3_result_null(context);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    sqlite3 *db;
    sqlite3_open(":memory:", &db);
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    sqlite3_create_function(db, "nformat", 1, SQLITE_UTF8, NULL, &nformat, NULL, NULL);
    sqlite3_prepare(db, "select nformat(1234)", -1, &stmt, NULL);
    sqlite3_step(stmt);
    printf("[%s]\n", sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I forgot to mention that the dev env is Android. So I havn't tried your solution.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is stored in a table and you are using [SQLite version 3.8.3](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html#version_3_8_3) or higher, then it is possible to accomplish what you want using a recursive CTE.

Below is a working SQL example of what I'm referring to.

```
WITH
    NBR_LIST_ETL AS
    (
    SELECT
        A.*,
            CAST(REPLACE(NBR_LENGTH % 3, 0, 3) AS INTEGER)
        AS SUB_STRING_LENGTH
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            ID, -- INTEGER PRIMARY KEY COLUMN
            NBR, -- INTEGER COLUMN YOU WANT TO FORMAT W/ COMMAS
                LENGTH(NBR)
            AS NBR_LENGTH
        FROM
            NBR_LIST A -- REPLACE NBR_LIST W/ YOUR TABLE NAME
        ) A
    ),
    NBR_FORMAT_RECURSIVE AS
    (
    SELECT
        ID,
            SUBSTR(NBR, 1, SUB_STRING_LENGTH)
        AS NBR_SEGMENT,
            SUBSTR(NBR, SUB_STRING_LENGTH + 1)
        AS NBR_REMAINING,
            NBR_LENGTH - SUB_STRING_LENGTH
        AS NBR_LENGTH
    FROM
        NBR_LIST_ETL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        ID,
            SUBSTR(NBR_REMAINING, 1, 3)
        AS NBR_SEGMENT,
            SUBSTR(NBR_REMAINING, 4)
        AS NBR_REMAINING,
            NBR_LENGTH - 3
        AS NBR_LENGTH
    FROM
        NBR_FORMAT_RECURSIVE
    WHERE
        NBR_LENGTH >= 3
    )
SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT(NBR_SEGMENT)
    AS NBR_FORMATTED
FROM
    NBR_FORMAT_RECURSIVE
GROUP BY
    ID
```

If your table contained the following numbers -

```
NBR
25271
7
29
75438175
342
212
4758
863
2313917
```

Then the query would output -

```
NBR_FORMATTED
25,271
7
29
75,438,175
342
212
4,758
863
2,313,917
```